# Setting and using MousePosition

Tags: c#, loops

Hey, i have kinda silly  problem, i need to set Point Pos as mouse current position in one if statement and in another statement move mouse cursor to setted position. First i need assign global Point variable but then Cursor moves to assigned variable and i don't want that happens.
Part of source:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
        {
            Point Pos = new Point(0, 0);

            if (m.Msg == 0x0312)
            {
                int id = m.WParam.ToInt32();
                if (id == 0)
                {
                    Pos.X = MousePosition.X;
                    Pos.Y = MousePosition.Y;  
                }
                if (id == 1)
                {
                    Cursor.Position = (Pos);
                }
            }
            base.WndProc(ref m);
        }
```

Comment: this is C# or what ? :D and where do you see a loop ?

Comment: oh lol, forgot to mention, this is in C# ^^ and i might be wrong... not loop, it's if statement

Comment: OK, I understand your problem but have no ideas about what you are trying to achive? Can you describe expected results

Comment: i need to set Pos to current mouse position when pressing first hotkey. Later i want to use that variable to move mouse cursor to that place. Problem is assigning Pos before statements, if i not assign it, i get error, if i assign it, mouse always moves to that place(0, 0).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to *capture* the mouse position and restore it later then you have to make the Pos variable a field of your class instead of a local variable of the method.  Like this:

```
    private Point Pos;

    protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        if (m.Msg == 0x0312)   // Trap WM_HOTKEY
        {
            switch (m.WParam.ToInt32()) {
               case 0: Pos = Cursor.Position; break;
               case 1: Cursor.Position = Pos; break;
            }
        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Comment: Ok, explaining more. I need to set Pos as current mouse position when pressing first hotkey (id == 0) and when i press second hotkey (id == 1) i need to move to that Pos. Problem is that when i not declare Pos, i get error and when i declare it, cursor moves to declared one when pressing second hotkey.

Comment: TY very much ^^, helpped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
Point pos = this.PointToClient(Cursor.Position);
```

Will return your actuall mouse position.

Comment: Well, this will makes source smaller, but not solves my problem